# Batch file to run all .bat files in folders and sub-folders with different names

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a simple script to run all .bat files in folders and sub-folders with their different names. here is an example :

> Main Folder> Bat Folder 1> Bat File 1.bat
>
> Main Folder> Bat Folder 2> Bat File 2.bat
>
> . . .
>
> Main Folder> Bat Folder N> Bat File N.bat

There are many topics out there asking the same question but the one that really worked for me was the following :

```
@echo off
pushd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Bat Folder 1\
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /a-d *.bat') do start "" "%%x"&timeout /t 2 >nul
popd
```

However the problem is the direct folder address. I can't manually enter the folder names and run them one by one. it would take a long time. I want the script to go through all folders and sub-folders ignoring their names and run them all. it would be better to have the script run inside the main folder instead of the folder address !

Comment: add the `/s` switch to the `dir` command.

Comment: how about the `pushd` line ? I removed it  and added `/s` to `('dir /b /a-d *.bat')` but it keeps executing empty bat files over and over probably due to the non-existent directory. like I said I want the `pushd` command to look for all file and folders. not just a fixed folder address !!

Comment: What about `start`'s `/d` switch? (btw: `pushd` is to switch directories. Nothing to do with files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a full answer, but I think this might help give you a start:

```
for /r "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop" %%a in (*.bat) do start "" "%%~a"
```

You might need `call "something.bat"` or `start "" cmd /c "something.bat"`

I suppose, if your batch files need a working directory, you could try this:

```
:: Make sure you're in the correct drive
c:
for /r "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop" %%a in (*.bat) do (
   cd "%%~pa"
   call "%%~a"
)
```

Comment: There's no difference between your script and AlexP's. I get the same error on both

Comment: You know the code in my topic works just fine. the only problem is the subfolders having different names. is it possible to replace it with something like %rootfolder% and call it from somewhere else ?

Comment: I thought that is exactly what I was demonstrating.  If you prefer, `for /r "%rootfolder%" %%a in (*.bat) do WhateverItIsYouWantToDoWith "%%~a"`  It will give you every .bat file in every subfolder of %rootfolder%.  No need for `cd` or `pushd`.

Comment: I ran this in the main folder and it did nothing : `for /r "%rootfolder%" %%a in (*.bat) do start "%%~a"`

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd "\Path\To\Main Folder"
for /r %%F in ("*.bat") do start /wait "" "%%~F"
```

`for /r` will iterate recursively over all `*.bat` files in all subdirectories to any depth.

Comment: I got the "not enough storage" error probably due to the bat file geting the .mp3 file names and storing them in a .txt file. I realized that the error had something to do with the empty window title `""` so I gave it a name like "Window Title" and it fixed the issue

Comment: however I get two separate windows when I run the bat file. one called **system32\cmd.exe** which shows the correct address for the bat file and the other one **Window Title** which is trying to run the .bat code in a wrong location : 
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Main Folder>for /F "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('dir /b *.mp3') do echo %~na|Music\Audio\MP3\%~a 1>>playlist.txt File Not Found`

Comment: @Timitom: (1) My code works fine. It is a standard technique. To test, replace `start` with `@echo start` to see exactly what it is trying to do. (2) What is it with you and the built-in `for` of Cmd.exe? What is the difference between a plain `for %%F in (*.mp3)` and your bizarre construction which tries to parse the output of `dir`?

Comment: (1) I tried your code with `@echo start` this time but it did nothing, (2) your batch file is supposed to run all .bat files in the sub-folders containing the following code: `for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.mp3') do echo %%~na^|Music\Audio\MP3\^%%~a>>playlist.txt` like I said it gets all mp3 file names and stores them in a .txt file. I would appreciate if you could replicate it to see if it works. it doesn't work on my end.

Comment: @Timitom: Call one of your batch scripts from outside its directory and see what happens...

Comment: Ah I see. Your batch scripts don't expect to be invoked from outside the directory they are in. Well, that's a bunch of badly written batch scripts. If a batch script wants to have the current working directory in a certain place it should change directory to that place. Sorry. (And anyway, if what you really want to do is traverse a subtree rooted in a certain directory and in each subdirectory get a list of MP3 files, then this is far from the best way to do it. The question is misleading; you do not really want to invoke all the batch scripts in a subtree, you want to make lists of files.)

Comment: I finally realized what's wrong with your code. If I add the subdirectory to the path like `pushd "\Path\Main Folder\Bat Folder 1"` then there would be no difference between your code and mine. both run the scrip without any problem. but like I said, subdirectories have different names and I can't manually insert the folder names one by one and then run the script. that's why I got the storage error because your code was actually running the script in the MAIN FOLDER.. !!

Comment: To repeat: if a script wants to have a certain current working directory *it must change directory itself*. A script should never assume that it will be invoked with the current directory set to its preferred place. If you won't or can't update your scripts you may try replacing `start /wait "" "%%~F"` with `pushd "%%~dpF" && start /wait "" "%%~F" && popd`. (Ah, and "folders" are pretty pictures in a GUI; the structures in a filesystem are called "directories"; the relationship between the folders shown in a GUI and the directories in the file system is not necessarily straightforward.)

Comment: excellent! almost there. now it runs the .bat file and creates the .txt file for the first folder perfectly and then prints the so-called "storage" error at the bottom  of the CMD (I don't think it matters this time because it creates the file successfully within the folder) however, for the next folder to start I came up with a Y/N command to terminate the old process and it happened once! now I have to type exit to terminate it. it makes it difficult to type exit/N for each and every folder. I added exit at the bottom of your .bat script but it didn't work.

Comment: avery_larry updated his code and it worked with no issue. thank you for your time anyway. it would be nice to fix the last issue so that I could mark yours as the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative. I used the code `dir /s /b *.bat > runall.bat` to get the full directory list and then replaced them all with `pushd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Bat Folder 1\Bat File 1.bat`

It's definitely not a good way to go but at least it fixed my issue.

Edit: It simply doesn't work. just reads the first line and ignores the rest.

Comment: You don't seem willing to learn what `for /r` does.  OR I am completely missing what you're trying to do.